# How to stop an event from firing twice?

Tags: javascript, css, events, logic, dom-events

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game to understand Dom Manipulation;
I've placed an `eventListener()` on all the individual divs that are inside the `#main-wrap` Div.
These divs contain SVG's of one cross and one circle that both hold CSS value `display:none`.
How once a player chooses his move do I make sure that the selected div cannot be chosen again?  (Because if it does get chosen again it changes it from a cross to a circle).
If you can figure it out and please help me.

```
const section1 = document.querySelector('.section-one');
const mainDiv = document.getElementById('main-wrap');
let whosGo = 0;

for (prop of mainDiv.children) {
    prop.addEventListener('click',addSVGs);
   
}

function addSVGs(e) {
    this.firstElementChild.classList = "cross";
    this.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.classList = "circle-display";
    whosGo ++;
    if(whosGo % 2 === 0) {
           this.firstElementChild.classList = "cross-display";
           this.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.classList = "circle";            
        }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting the code for drawing your shapes into an else block.

```
function addSVGs(e) {
    whosGo ++;
    if(whosGo % 2 === 0) {
           this.firstElementChild.classList = "cross-display";
           this.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.classList = "circle";            
    }else{
           this.firstElementChild.classList = "cross";
           this.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.classList = "circle-display";
     }     
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I tried that code snippet but its the same result  thank you for helping though :)